# Capped collections vs Queues

Tags: mongodb, data-structures, queue, capped-collections

I'm trying to understand what is the capped collection is, specifically in context of MongoDB, and what would be the difference in compare with queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capped collection will remove oldest document when it reaches it limit, so that could be an issue if there is a need to process **ALL** documents from capped collection.

> [from mongo](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/): Capped collections work in a way similar to circular
>   buffers: once a collection fills its allocated space, it makes room
>   for new documents by overwriting the oldest documents in the
>   collection.

comparing to queue:

1. queue will not remove records when full (it could throw an exception
   like out of memory)
2. queue can remove record when dequeued - in capped collection you need to delete it on your own
3. capped collection cleanup: if capped collection size  is 40 documents - then when 41st document is added -> the 1st entry is removed

I think this the most important things - any comments welcome!

Comment: Thanks, okay to recap :)  
- Queues can remove old elements (FILO) automatically.  
- In capped collections cleanup happens explicitly (?)

Comment: @dmi3y in capped collection there is no cleanup. The older documents are just removed from it. So if capped collection size  is 40 documents - then when 41 is added -> 1 is removed

Answer (score 1):

**CAPPED** collection in mongodb is implementation of [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

From official documentation

> Capped collections are fixed-size collections that support high-throughput operations that insert and retrieve documents based on insertion order. Capped collections work in a way similar to circular buffers: once a collection fills its allocated space, it makes room for new documents by overwriting the oldest documents in the collection.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info, though can you elaborate more, this does not really make things clear for me.